# Fast saving and retrieving of python data structures for an autocorrect program?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pickle, trie, autocorrect

So, I have written an autocomplete and autocorrect program in Python 2. I have written the autocorrect program using the approach mentioned is Peter Norvig's blog on how to write a spell checker, [link](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html).

Now, I am using a trie data structure implemented using nested lists. I am using a trie as it can give me all words starting with a particular prefix.At the leaf would be a tuple with the word and a value denoting the frequency of the word.For e.g.- the words bad,bat,cat would be saved as-

```
['b'['a'['d',('bad',4),'t',('bat',3)]],'c'['a'['t',('cat',4)]]]
```

Where 4,3,4 are the number times the words have been used or the frequency value. Similarly I have made a trie of about 130,000 words of the english dictionary and stored it using cPickle.

Now, it takes about 3-4 seconds for the entire trie to be read each time.The problem is each time a word is encountered the frequency value has to be incremented and then the updated trie needs to be saved again. As you can imagine it would be a big problem waiting each time for 3-4 seconds to read and then again that much time to save the updated trie each time. I will need to perform a lot of update operations each time the program is run and save them.

Is there a faster or efficient way to store a large data structure which repeatedly will be updated? How are the data structures of the autocorrect programs in IDEs and mobile devices saved & retrieved so fast? I am open to different approaches as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things come to mind.

1) Split the data. Say use 26 files each storing the tries starting with a certain character. You can improve it so that you use a prefix. This way the amount of data you need to write is less.

2) Don't reflect everything to disk. If you need to perform a lot of operations do them in ram(memory) and write them down at then end. If you're afraid of data loss, you can checkpoint your computation after some time X or after a number of operations.

3) Multi-threading. Unless you program only does spellchecking, it's likely there are other things it needs to do. Have a separate thread that does loading writing so that it doesn't block everything while it does disk IO. Multi-threading in python is a bit tricky but it can be done.

4) Custom structure. Part of the time spent in serialization is invoking serialization functions. Since you have a dictionary for everything that's a lot of function calls. In the perfect case you should have a memory representation that matches exactly the disk representation. You would then simply read a large string and put it into your custom class (and write that string to disk when you need to). This is a bit more advanced and likely the benefits will not be that huge especially since python is not so efficient in playing with bits, but if you need to squeeze the last bit of speed out of it, this is the way to go.

Comment: @gospelslide: You may want to look at the `klepto` package (I'm the author), which is built to facilitate the excellent suggestions above.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to move serialization to a separate thread and run it periodically. You don't need to re-read your data each time because you already have the latest version in memory. This way your program would be responsive to the user while the data is being saved to the disk. The saved version on disk may be lagging and the latest updates may get lost in case of program crash but this shouldn't be a big issue for your use case, I think.

It depends on a particular use case and environment but, I think, most programs having local data sets sync them using multi-threading.